# Volatile variable and synchronized setter and getter

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, volatile

I have thread class that has two variables `var1` and `var2` that might be accessed from different threads. Can we assume that using `var2` via `synchronized` getter and setter is the same like using `volatile` `var1` without them?

```
public class Processor extends Thread
{
    public volatile  boolean var1 = false
    private boolean var2 = false

    synchronized boolean getVar2 ()
    {
        return var2;
    }

    synchronized boolean setVar2 (boolean value)
    {
        return var2=value;
    }


    public void run()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Just setting a variable to be volatile isn't a substitute for synchronisation if that's what you're asking?

Comment: What is the idea behind the body of that setter? `return var2 = value;` That's abnormal, so need to know what you're trying to achieve there.

Comment: Also var1 is a non-final public boolean, not sure if the above is real code or just to demonstrate an example, but it's probably bad news...

Comment: In this example, there is no difference.  In other examples, there is a big difference.  You need to read the Oracle Tutorial on Concurrency (specifically, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) to understand the difference between synchronization and atomic operations.

Answer (score 3):

In this case yes. Because neither synchronized block both reads and writes the value.

Suppose we wanted to react to a value change, that would require both a read of the current value and a write of the new. For this, `volatile` would not be suitable:

```
synchronized void setVar(boolean value) {
  if (var != value) {
    var = value;
    someOnChangeMethod();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the two are equivalent wrt memory visibility. You lose automicity that `synchronized` offers if you have to do some check-then-set.